# Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, soap

We've implemented a Web Service (Using Visual Studio .asmx file) and when we try to POST the client given XML (With Firefox Poster) we get the error:

```
<soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode><faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace client.Namespace was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.
```

Is there a way in Visual Studio webservices to change the validation xsd or to ignore the validation at all?
Is there a way to change the Webservice line below through Visual Studio?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Keep in mind that the client cannot change the xml request….

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247971/how-i-change-soap-xml-web-service-in-c/51264211#51264211